# Can a 10 fold cross validation with a decently large number of features overfit?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm fitting a model with a varying number of features and experimenting with the number of folds for cross validation. When I train on a random 60/20/20 split for train/test/validation and choose the best performing model (and then check to see if the best performed reasonably well on the validation set), I get a simple accuracy of about 45%. This is with the full set of 80 features. With just the top 30 features in the same procedure the results are similar (~45%)

When I take out the validation set (having chosen my particular algorithm/model, gradient boosted trees) and train with a 10 fold cross validation (so training on each fold with a 90/10 split of train test), the accuracy goes up considerably (~70%) with 80 features. With the top 30 features it moves up marginally to 50%.

Is this overfitting due to the large number of features? Potentially as a combination from the high cardinality features and the large number of features to create a large number of splits in the individual trees?

The end model chosen is an ensemble of a few models, most of which are xgboost gbts. The total number of observations is ~5500

Comment: Please give some more details on the problem. What model do you use? how many samples are there? Those are crucial details about the problem to theoretically think about the overfitting problem. Ofcouse bugs are also possible, but I assume you have checked.

Comment: The model chosen is an ensemble of a few models, most of which are xgboost gbts. The total number of observations is ~5500

Comment: I checked the correlation and some of the features are correlated. Out of the 80 maybe 10 or so are strongly correlated (.6+).

Comment: This is more of a stats question than a programming question. It might be more at home on Cross Validated